# Pros and cons of doing PhD research in an applied math topic at a non-math dept,

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-process, graduate-school

What are the pros and cons of doing a PhD in an applied math topic from a non-math dept? Let's say I found PhD programs in a research area that are in  aerospace / mechanical engineering departments at some schools and in math departments at other schools.

Comment: You can look at the programs of studies and the course descriptions carefully.  Also, look at the faculty bios of the two departments.  You may also check what the university's commitment to interdisciplinary study is like.  For example, can you have a committee member from another department?

Comment: Are you planning to go into academia? Might be relevant if you are aiming for a mathematics department in the future.

Comment: @AJK, excellent point - I will lean towards applied math departments then ... thanks so much,

Comment: Don't let that be decisive, just something to keep in mind - and for other people to think about when writing an answer!